# SlidingFragmentActivity: How to save instance of view pager with different fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, screen-orientation, viewpagerindicator

I'm using ABS and ViewPagerIndicatior. I have three fragment with custom list view in the my view pager that fills with custom adapter. now when I change orientation from land to port or vice verse, onActivityCreated calls again when orientation changes and views recreate again

main activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity implements     ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

protected SliderLeft sliderLeft;
protected SliderRight sliderRight;
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mViewPager;
TitlePageIndicator mPageIndicator;
FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
SubMenu subMenu1;
private Menu mainMenu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.slider_menu_frame);

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowleft);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    //int heightOfScreen = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    sm.setBehindWidth(width / 2); //sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // set viewPager and viewPagerIndicator
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    mPageIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mPageIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mPageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    mPageIndicator.setCurrentItem(1);

}


}
```

My application's UI acts same as yahoo answer app.

The view pager adapter is:

```
public class FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            Fragment_Review fragment_review = new Fragment_Review();
            Bundle args0 = new Bundle();
            args0.putInt(Fragment_Activities.ARG_OBJECT, i);
            fragment_review.setArguments(args0);
            fragment = fragment_review;
            break;
        case 1:
            Fragment fragment_activities = new Fragment_Activities();
            Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
            args1.putInt(Fragment_Activities.ARG_OBJECT, i);
            fragment_activities.setArguments(args1);
            fragment = fragment_activities;
            break;
        case 2:
            Fragment_Answer fragment_answerit = new Fragment_Answer();
            Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
            args2.putInt(Fragment_Activities.ARG_OBJECT, i);
            fragment_answerit.setArguments(args2);
            fragment = fragment_answerit;
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    CharSequence pageTitle = "";

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            pageTitle = "tiile";
            break;
        case 1:
            pageTitle = "title";
            break;
        case 2:
            pageTitle = "tille";
            break;
    }

    return pageTitle;
}

}
```

all fragment inside view pager extends from SherlockFragment.

```
public class Fragment_Review extends SherlockFragment implements PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener<ListView> {

private List<Data> allData;
private CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
private PullToRefreshListView mPullRefreshListView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ptr_list_fragment, container, false);
    mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView) v.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    allData = new ArrayList<Data>();
    mPullRefreshListView.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_UP_TO_REFRESH);
    customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), allData);
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(lazyQuestionListAdapter);
    new GetData().execute(getString(R.string.url) + "get_data.php");
}
}
```

when data receive from server the adapter will be update.

please guide me how to save instance of all fragment in orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that (in fragment):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    allData = new ArrayList<Data>();
    customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), allData);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mPullRefreshListView.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_UP_TO_REFRESH);
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(lazyQuestionListAdapter);

    //ADD condition for load data from network (like only if adapter.isEmpty())
    new GetData().execute(getString(R.string.url) + "get_data.php");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it is a normal. If you want avoid this, you must add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" for this activity in your manifest...